# Gnome Disk Utility - "SMART Data & Self Tests..." Option greyed out

Tags: hard-drive, 22.04, gnome-disk-utility

The option for "SMART Data & Self Tests..." is not available (greyed out) in Gnome Disk Utility on 22.04. I have smartmontools installed and can read information about the disk, including test results and errors by running smartctl commands. I'm hoping to get this working in Gnome because I'd like to get notifications if errors start showing up.

Comment: Is your user in `disk` group ?

Comment: Does your disk drive support SMART?

Comment: @pasmanpasmański Check for `disk` group membership by `id`. Become a member of the `disk` group with `sudo adduser "$USER` disk`, then logout & login (groups are set up at `login`).

Answer (score 0):

The option was also greyed out in my case and when running the `skdump` command it showed that ATA SMART was not supported. I wasn't able to get Gnome Disks to work, but I could still read the SMART data through `smartctl`.

You can install the package with:

```
sudo apt install smartmontools
```

and then read the SMART details with:

```
sudo smartctl --all /dev/nvme1n1
```

*Remember to replace `/dev/nvme1n1` with the location of your drive*